# need help around IQueryable query result

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Assuming following tables

**Person**

- id
- name

**PersonTeam**

- id
- person_id
- is_supervisor
- team_id

**Team**

- id

**TimeSheet**

- id
- team_id

I would like to obtain all TimeSheets for a supervisor. I got name of supervisor, then I need select which team he is got supervisor role. Then select all time sheet of those teams.

I believe following query does

```
var allTimeSheets = ctx.PersonTeam.Where(y => y.Person.name == supervisor_name).Where(x => x.is_supervisor == true).Select(z => z.Team).Select(t => t.TimeSheet);
```

afer this operation I cannot understand *allTimeSheets* is a

```
 IQueryable<ICollection<TimeSheet>>
```

I expected more a

```
 <ICollection<TimeSheet>>
```

or any *IEnumrable*.

Then questions are :

1. why I got that kind of result ?
2. how to obtain *TimeSheet[]* where I got *IQueryable < ICollection < TimeSheet > >* ?

Comment: Add `.ToList` to the end of your query.

Comment: ToList() gives a List<ICollection<TimeSheet>>, not really what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why did I get that kind of result ?  I expected more a `ICollection<TimeSheet>`

<strike>An `IQueryable<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`.  The reason it's returning an `IQueryable` is so you can chain other methods like `OrderBy` onto it and project those to the actual SQL.</strike>

I just realized what you're asking.  To "flatten" the collection of collections, use `SelectMany` instead of two chained `Select`s:

```
var allTimeSheets = ctx.PersonTeam
                       .Where(y => y.Person.name == supervisor_name 
                                && y.is_supervisor == true)
                       .SelectMany(z => z.Team, (z, t) => t.TimeSheet);
```

The answer to your second question still applies:

> how do I obtain a `TimeSheet[]` from a `IQueryable<ICollection<TimeSheet>>`

(first of all use the first part to change to an `IQueryable<TimeSheet>`)

You can call one of the "conversion" methods like `ToArray`, `ToList`, to "hydrate" the query into a concrete type.

You can also call "AsEnumerable`to cast to an`IEnumerable`to convert the query to Linq-To-Objects, which has better support for custom functions in sorts, filters, etc.  Note that calling`AsEnunerable` does no *immediately* fetch the objects, but will do as as soon as the collection in enumerated.

Comment: Excatly I want to flat the result. But SelectMany() you wrote not works as it. Anyway that is interesting. I'm working around.

Comment: `(...).Select(z => z.Team).SelectMany( t => t.TimeSheet);` is better. I suppose that about DB relationship.